# This connect wall is a security risk!

Tags: word, connect-wall

Unlike normal [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall)s which have four groups of four, this one has five groups of four. The five groups may each be summarised by one word and those five words are in turn related.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JADE | JAZZ | JEDI | JUBILEE |
| WATER | WAVES | SANDY | TEAPOT |
| UNION | MILE | POINT | MUTUAL |
| BERKSHIRE | GRIND | FULLER | RUSH |
| TASSEL | WERNER | BEEHIVE | MAG |

What are the groups of four and what are the corresponding group words? Why is this puzzle a security risk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title refers to

> the [D-Day *Daily Telegraph* crossword affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Day_Daily_Telegraph_crossword_security_alarm)

which of course also explains the "security risk" and identifies the commonality between the groups, which are

> *Juno*: JADE JEDI MAG WAVES. These are all instruments on the NASA probe *Juno*, orbiting Jupiter.
>  *Sword*: FULLER GRIND POINT TASSEL. These are all parts of a sword (perhaps stretching it a bit for the last one).
>  *Utah*: BEEHIVE JAZZ TEAPOT SANDY. These are all things associated with Utah:  it's known as "the Beehive state", it's home to a notable basketball team called the Utah Jazz, the [Utah teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_teapot) is a standard shape in computer graphics. Besides "sandy" being a reasonable description of much of Utah, it is also the name of a city there.
>  *Gold*: JUBILEE MILE RUSH WATER. [Golden jubilee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_jubilee), several [Golden Miles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Mile), [Gold rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_rush), [Barry Goldwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_rush).
>  *Omaha*: BERKSHIRE MUTUAL UNION WERNER. Omaha is home to [Berkshire Hathaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkshire_Hathaway), [Mutual of Omaha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_of_Omaha), the [Union Omaha soccer team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Omaha), and [Werner Enterprises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Enterprises).

Comment: I actually had Union Pacific and not Union Omaha, but it still fits.

Comment: Interesting. For what it's worth, rot13(GRNCBG) immediately made me think of rot13(Hgnu), and that plus the title made me pretty confident of what the theme would be very quickly. It took a while to figure out exactly what all the groups were, though. Especially as when I looked up the relevant list I didn't notice rot13(Whab) at first :-).

Comment: Though I'm curious about one possible red herring. Is the presence of both TEAPOT and FULLER a deliberate reference to the obvious-if-you-know-it novel by Charles Stross, or is that coincidence?

Comment: I have never read that novel (_The Fuller Memorandum_?) In fact the only major novel I have in my home library is _Anna Karenina_.

Comment: Yes, _The Fuller Memorandum_. Certainly not a "major novel" but fun if you happen to enjoy the particular kind of thing it is. I shall not elaborate on exactly why teapots are relevant because I don't think I can do so in a way that's any use but not spoilery.